# Add border to prime faces accordion panel

Tags: css, primefaces, accordion

How can I add border to

I have tried the following but dint work.

```
<p:accordionPanel style="width:100%; border:1px; ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add border to `accordion panel`:

```
            <style type="text/css">
                .ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-reset.ui-widget-content{
                    border:1px solid !important;
                }
            </style>
```

If you want to add border to tab inside accordion, you use:

```
<p:accordionPanel style="border:1px solid">
```